# Fill entire content with a background image in Flex/spark

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I created a 960x640px image which i want to use as background picture for any type of mobile device by scalling the image to the device s resolution.

How can i achieve this?

i tried:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="MainView">

     <s:Image width="100%" height="100%" fillMode="scale" scaleMode="stretch"
         source="assets/background.jpg" />
        <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>  
 </s:View>
```

This looks good in the design view, it fill the whole screen but when i run the application everyting is really messy (the image is a lot smaller or a lot bigger than the mobile emulator screen)

Is there a better way to do this? Is it possbile to set a background-image directly on the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set the fillMode="repeat"
this will repeat the image to fill the view